# Retrofit Implicit OAuth 2.0 authentication

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, retrofit, okhttp

I am developing a simple StackOverflow client. As the doc says [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) I have to use implicit OAuth flow with redirection url. I open CustomTabs and pass this link https://stackoverflow.com/oauth for this. In the app, there are several screens with actions that requeire to be authenticated. My question is how to properly handle 403 error in each screen so when I open CustomTabs it redirects to the same screen, when the not-authorized response received.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add this In Retrofit BaseService Class

private static class TokenInterceptor implements Interceptor {

```
    private TokenInterceptor() {

    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {

        Request initialRequest = chain.request();

        initialRequest = initialRequest.newBuilder()
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .build();

        Response response = chain.proceed(initialRequest);

        return response;
    }
}
```